# How to have a fixed column in Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a page with Bootstrap that has two columns like below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">Fixed</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to make the first column fixed position so it stays while scrolling but the other one will be normal and holds long text.

How can I do it?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4zuo6dm7/1/)

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for Bootstrap's affix. GetBootstrap.com.

Comment: @Christina thanks for your comment. I tired affix but could not get it working. putting that code here would be another subject that's why I didn't share it. Can you provide an example of affix that can work ? Thanks

Comment: There's examples galore all over the place. It's a pain in the ass to work with as is most of the solutions.

Comment: @Christina I made a seperate topic for getting affix worked in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856368/why-does-the-width-of-affix-column-changes-while-scrolling). Can you check it please. Thanks

Comment: The answer you got is correct. You can also use jQuery to get the width and update that on resize.

Answer (score 1):

Use '`affix`'

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            <div class="panel panel-default affix">
                <div class="panel-body">Fixed</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/lLftRLexWR)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few options:

1) Use Bootstrap's [Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) (thanks @Christina)

2) `position:sticky` - with [limited support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)

3) [stickyjs](http://stickyjs.com/) - a simple js lib

4) custom bake your own solution, something like:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {

  var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

  var target = $('div').offset().top

  if ( offset > target ) {
    // do stuff
  }
})
```

Comment: Bootstrap comes with an affix plugin