# Why does the width of affix column change while scrolling in Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap I made two columns one with affix to make it fixed while scrolling and one normal column.
Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4zuo6dm7/2/)

This is my code so far:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" id="myScrollspy">
            <div class="panel panel-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0">
                <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

If you check the demo, as soon as you scroll down, the width of the small column which has affix changes. Why is that?

Is there any idea to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: From the docs: Use the affix plugin via data attributes or manually with your own JavaScript. In both situations, you must provide CSS for the positioning and width of your affixed content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when the small column hits the top of the window, it's position property is set to fixed. If an element is fixed positioned, it is taken out of the normal flow of the page. So, it fills as much space as it need. 
You have to set the width for the small column when it becomes fixed.